# Deriving principal components by minimizing reconstruction error

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

**Problem**. Suppose that $\Sigma := \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_{1}, \dots, \sigma_{p})$, where $\sigma_{1} \geq \sigma_{2} \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_{p} > 0$. Consider maximizing $\| \Sigma \Gamma \|_{F}$, where $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ is the Frobenius norm, under the constraint that $\Gamma \in \mathbb{M}_{p, q}$ has orthonormal columns, i.e., $\Gamma^\top \Gamma = I_{q}$, and $q$ is a known constant smaller than $p$. Show that $\Gamma_{*}$ solves the problem if the columns of $\Gamma$ are permutations and possibly sign flips of the canonical basis $e_{1}, e_{2}, \dots, e_{q} \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Motivation**. I stumbled upon this problem while reading the explanation on PCA in the book *The Elements of Statistical Learning 2ed.* (a copy can be found on one author's website). The authors give a partial derivation in Section 14.5.1 of the book. I will use different notations to explain the motivation here.

Let $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n}$ be $n$ observations in the $\mathbb{R}^{p}$. For simplicity we assume that $n > p$ and $x_{i}$ are linearly independent. These observations are collected into data matrix $X \in \mathbb{M}_{n, p}$:
$$
X := \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}^\top \\
x_{2}^\top \\
\vdots \\
x_{p}^\top 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We want to find $n$ points on a $q$-dimensional affine subspace $\{ \mu + W\beta: \beta \in \mathbb{R}^{q} \}$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $W \in \mathbb{M}_{p, q}$ has orthonormal columns, to minimize the **reconstruction error**, which is defined as
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| x_{i} - \mu - W\beta_{i} \|_2^{2} .
$$
By partial minimization, we can show that optimal $\mu_{*}$ and $\beta_{i*}$ satisfy $\mu_{*} \in \bar{x} + \mathrm{ker}(I - W W^{\top})$ and $\beta_{i*} = W^{\top}(x_i - \bar{x})$, where $\bar{x} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i}$ is the sample mean. For simplicity we choose $\mu_{*} = \bar{x}$, and the problem becomes
$$
\min_{W} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| x_{i} - \bar{x} - W W^{\top} (x_{i} - \bar{x}) \|_{2}^{2}, \quad \text{s.t. } W^\top W = I.
$$
This corresponds to equation 14.53 in the book. Without loss of generality, we assume that $\bar{x} = 0$ in the sequel.

Next, let
$$
X = U \Sigma V^{\top}
$$
be the reduced form SVD, where $U \in \mathbb{M}_{n, p}$ has orthonormal columns, $\Sigma$ is the $p \times p$ diagonal matrix of singular values in nonincreasing order, and $V \in \mathbb{M}_{p, p}$ is real orthogonal matrix. The authors claim without proof that the first $q$ columns of $V$ form a solution to the optimization problem. (See the paragraph below equation 14.54 in the book).

---

**Solving the optimization problem using Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem**. With some linear algebra we can show that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| x_{i} - W W^{\top} x_i \|_{2}^{2} = \| X - X W W^{\top} \|_{F}^2.
$$
The matrix $X W W^{\top}$ can be viewed as a rank-$q$ approximation to $X$. By the [Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) for Frobenius norm, the first $q$ columns of $V$ form a solution to the problem.

Although this solves the problem, I'm left wondering if there is a **more elementary proof**. So here is my attempt.

---

**Attempt to come up with an elementary proof**. By the Pythagoras equality, we have
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| x_{i} - W W^{\top} x_{i} \|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| x_{i} \| ^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| W W^{\top} x_{i} \| ^ 2.
$$
Therefore, the optimization problem becomes
$$
\max_{W} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \| W W^\top x_{i} \|^2_2 , \quad \text{s.t. } W^\top W = I.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\max_{W} \| X W \|_{F}, \quad \text{s.t. } W^\top W = I.
$$
Next,
$$
\| X W \|_{F} = \| U \Sigma V^\top W \|_{F} = \| \Sigma V^\top W \|_{F} .
$$
Define $\Gamma := V^\top W$, which is a $p \times q$ matrix. We have $\Gamma^\top \Gamma = I$, so $\Gamma$ has orthonormal columns. The optimization problem now becomes
$$
\max_{\Gamma} \| \Sigma \Gamma \|_{F}, \quad \text{s.t. } \Gamma^{\top} \Gamma = I.
$$

From here on, I don't know how to proceed. I've thought about letting $\gamma_{i}, 1 \leq i \leq q$ be the columns of $\Gamma$, so that
$$
\| \Sigma \Gamma \|_{F}^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{q} \| \Sigma \gamma_{i} \|_{2}^{2}.
$$
If we optimize *sequentially*, subject to the constraint that $\gamma_{i}$ are orthonormal, then we could obtain $e_{1}, \cdots e_{q}$ as one solution. But I don't know how to show that this sequential solution is also a simultaneous solution.

As another attempt, I tried to use the Lagrange multiplier method. Write
$$
L(\Gamma, \Lambda) = - \| \Sigma \Gamma \|_{F}^{2} + tr(\Lambda (\Gamma^\top \Gamma - I)),
$$
where $\Lambda$ is a matrix of Lagrange multipliers. By the first order condition, we obtain
$$
\Gamma^{\top} \Sigma^{2} = \Lambda \Gamma^{\top} .
$$
But then we I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C=\Gamma\,\Gamma^\ast$ is a rank-$q$ orthogonal projection. Each of its diagonal element $c_i$ is between $0$ and $1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^pc_i=\operatorname{tr}(C)=\operatorname{rank}(C)=q$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\Sigma\Gamma\|_F^2
&=\operatorname{tr}(\Gamma^\ast\Sigma^2\Gamma)
=\operatorname{tr}(\Gamma \Gamma^\ast\Sigma^2)
=\operatorname{tr}(C\Sigma^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^pc_i\sigma_i^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^qc_i\sigma_i^2+\sum_{i=q+1}^pc_i\sigma_i^2\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^qc_i\sigma_i^2+\sum_{i=q+1}^pc_i\sigma_{q+1}^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^qc_i\sigma_i^2+\left(q-\sum_{i=1}^qc_i\right)\sigma_{q+1}^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^qc_i\sigma_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^q(1-c_i)\sigma_{q+1}^2\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^qc_i\sigma_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^q(1-c_i)\sigma_i^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^q\sigma_i^2.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular, equality holds when $c_1=\cdots=c_q=1$ and $c_i=0$ when $i>q$, i.e., when $\Gamma=\pmatrix{Q\\ 0}$ for some unitary matrix $Q$.

Comment: I forgot these elementary properties of an orthogonal projector.. thanks a lot for the answer!